# Hacking a pH meter and digital burette to partially automate a titration

Tags: titration

This is a chemistry question about experimental techniques and technology.

I would like to connect a digital burette (Brand Titrette) and a pH meter to a computer and automate data acquisition to Excel. The pH meter would be connected to a platinum electrode with which I am measuring electrical potential during a titration. The objective is streamlined data collection to generate a titration curve (x-axis: volume, y-axis: potential) that would be used to identify the equivalence point of the titration.

Can anyone recommend an open source software that can be used to link excel to instruments?

Thank you,
Jeremy

Thank you,
JS

Comment: I suspect you are asking about a hardware hack, so if you are at the university, I'd talk to the guys at the workshop.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about technical aspects of chemistry tools.